# RCloud - How to view files in home directory?

Tags: r, rcloud

If I use the following command to download a file:

```
download.file("https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/exdata%2Fdata%2Fhousehold_power_consumption.zip", 
              "file.zip", mode="wb")
```

It appears to download successfully:

**trying URL**:
'https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/exdata%2Fdata%2Fhousehold_power_consumption.zip'

> Content type 'application/zip' length 20640916 bytes (19.7 MB)
>
> downloaded 19.7 MB

However, if I use this command to list files in my home directory:

`list.files(rcloud.home(), full.names=TRUE)`

I don't see the file.  In addition, this command:

`unzip("file.zip")`

Does not return anything (no error or file).

Is this file being downloaded to another directory?  Is there a pane similar to the "File" pane in RStudio where I can see the files in my local (home?) directory, please?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`download.file` will download to the working directory, which you can find with `getwd()`. So, the following works:

```
> list.files(getwd()) 

[1] "file.zip"
```

We could consider changing the working directory to the home directory, or adding a file browser panel, in the future.

Comment: I also created an [RCloud notebook](https://rcloud.social/view.html?notebook=af5b11b482f8e6eb8c51ffb984ac8947) which uses RCloud API to download and unzip a file; you need to have RCloud Data Scientist access (in other words, [login](https://rcloud.social/login.R) to RCloud - if necessary create a Github account) in order to view the source code.